# mod_rewrite rule: How to match jpg, gif, png and bmp files

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rule that will get the extension of every file from the url. I need to match all jpg, gif, png and bmp files. This is for a watermark application. Currently, it only matches jpg and Jpg. How to match all four extensions?

Here is what I currently have so far.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.[jJgG].*)$ /test.php?i=$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(jpg|gif|bmp|png))$ /test.php?i=$1 [NC]
```

Note that the rule in your post is actually matching any file whose extension starts with a J or a G.

Comment: Your right about matching any letter starting with a j or a g. It was matching gifs as well but for some reason, wouldn't match png. I'd get a 500 server error.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(jpg|gif|png|bmp)(\?.*)?)$   /test.php?i=$1 [NC]
```

The `[NC]` enables case insensible matching. Additionally, the first `.+` cares for non-empty file names. The `(\?.*)?` part matches optional query strings.

Comment: Hi Boldewyn, thanks for your answer. I need to join so that I can vote up.